# PEG-silane treatment: why incubate for 18 hours at 60 degrees Celsius?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, protocol

I am conducting a biochemistry-related experiment and I have been unable to understand a step which is commonly performed.
My aim in this step is to apply a PEG (Polyethylene glycol) silane layer.

After immersing indium tin oxide (ITO) slides in a PEG-concentration, the slides are incubated for 18 hours at a temperature of 60 degrees Celsius.

Can you tell me why the incubation is performed? And why for 18 hours and at 60 degrees Celsius?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: please clarify the experimental aim and procedure. And please expand the abbreviations at least once.

Comment: plus.. this question doesn't come under the domain of biology. try chemistry SE if your *actual* question doesn't involve any biological principle

Answer (score 3):

The binding of proteins (and cells) to glass (or silicon) surfaces can be prevented by coating the glass with polyethylene glycol (PEG) groups. PEG-silane is a reagent used to create this coating.

PEG-silane (the image shows a methoxy- version) (image taken from [here](http://www.laysanbio.com/index.php?src=directory&view=products&refno=303&srctype=products_detail); no connection)  will coat glass surfaces because the silane portion (right hand end of the structure shown) will react with -OH groups on the glass surface.

I can't help with the part of the question about time and temperature of incubation, but it seems longer and hotter than protocols I have seen. Perhaps the indium tin oxide (ITO) coating on the slides has something to do with it?

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Alan! What I do not understand yet from your answer is: where do the OH-groups on the glass surface come from?

Comment: Google Images: glass chemical structure

Answer (score 1):

please go through the journal: S. Jo, K. Park, Biomaterials 21 (2000) 605-616.
The time and temperature probably helps to hydrolyze, formation of hydrogen bond and covalent bond formation. Hope this paper will help you.
Good luck!